# Ajax get data to get another ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I need some pointer about combining nested ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: generalurl + "/Chore" + objectid + "?$expand=Process",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        list = $(data)[0]["TM1.ChoreProcessRel"];
        res = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
            var e = list[i];

            GetDirectories(e.ID, function (d) {
                alert(d); //this is working fine already   
            });

            //I just want to include d on the below statement but I'm still getting undefined
            res.push({
                title: "" + e.Name, key: e.LogicalName + d, 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the GetDirectory code

```
function GetDirectories(choreid, callback) {
    var theurl = webapiurl + '/Models' + getTopUrlVars()["model"] + '/ChoreProcess(' + choreid + ')?$expand=Process';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: theurl,
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response["TM1.ChoreProcessesProcess"][0].ID);
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I tried using global variable but then the first value is "".

Comment: don't use callback in getDirectories because success encapsulate ajax request. You try set res.push in response instead of use callback.

Answer (score 0):

if you have return in getDirectories, try use variable

```
var d = GetDirectories(e.ID, function (d) {
                alert(d); //this is working fine already   
            });

            //I just want to include d on the below statement but I'm still getting undefined
            res.push({
                title: "" + e.Name, key: e.LogicalName + d, 
            });
```

Comment: I have tried set res.push in the success response and it didn't work. It's just not detecting the res. 

I also have tried the var d = GetDirectories and inside the function, do a return d and that also didn't work.

Comment: hmm, but you really need call nested ajax requests? IMHO its bad app design. If you call ajax and your backend return data, it can return all data in one time. And set timer loop for refresh this ajax. This what you have it can be overkill for some clients (browser). Try think if you really need do this way.